# Perl regular expression to find a previous CSV field

Tags: regex, perl, csv

A common scenario I'm hitting in CSV files is to find a particular field and then capture the field immediately prior or immediately after that field. For example, in the following CSV line, my regex is hunting for the state field 'NSW', but I also need to capture the surrounding fields:

```
So Cross Univ, Sch Environm Sci & Engn, Lismore, NSW 2480
```

This is my attempt so far:

```
(?P<city>([^,]*?))(?P<state>\b(WA|QLD|NSW|VIC|SA|NT|TAS)\b)
```

It's capturing the state but not the city.

Here, the scenario is an address, but it may not always be the case. So, I'm trying to come up with a generic regex that will search for a CSV field and capture the fields either side.

Has any one else come across this too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It *is* capturing a string for `city`--and exactly as you specified. When I tried your regex, I got the city as `' '`, which you may have missed if you printed the value out without delimiters.

Your regex does not allow for a comma: A string of non-commas is not a comma, and neither are any of the defined values for `state`. Thus your regex captures the only string it can,  a non-comma before one of those strings, a single space. You didn't say it couldn't be a space, you just said it couldn't contain a comma.

```
/(?P<city>([^,]*?)),\s*(?P<state>\b(WA|QLD|NSW|VIC|SA|NT|TAS)\b)/
```

works.

And yes, even old pros can, *daily*, see the problem of not capturing what we thought we were specifying, but what we were actually specifying. Knowing how to debug a regular expression and how to print out *exactly* what you are capturing, is half the battle. Of course, experience in the regex jungles can also help you spot something like looking for text on both sides of a comma, but not actually including a comma in your pattern.

Answer (score 2):

Separate **Parsing** from **Validation**.

There are lots of good modules out there for parsing csv, like [`Text::CSV`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text%3a%3aCSV) and [`Text::CSV_XS`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text%3a%3aCSV_XS).  Even though parsing CSV looks easy and might be easy in a lot of cases, you should get in the habit of always using these modules.

Then after you've successfully parsed your data, then you can throw in a requirement, like the state being of a list of values:

```
if (grep {$state eq $_} qw(WA QLD NSW VIC SA NT TAS)) {
```

Comment: Thank you @Miller. I used `Text::CSV` for the initial parsing, but then I found there were comma-separated lists _within_ the CSV fields. Rather than parse the field again, my plan was to zero in on a few pieces of data.

Comment: Parse the fields again.  Or if that column a simplified comma separated list, then you can just use a `split`.   For reasons why you should still stick with a CSV Parser even if your column requires additional processing, just read this similar question from today: [`Perl regex store matches in array`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23921738/1733163)